# Kivy Save file in Documents on Android

Tags: python, kivy

My kivy app needs an export button that exports a text file. I know the standard python way to save files but I can't get what I need on an android device. Ideally, the text file will be easily accessible outside the app, like in the `"My Files/Documents"` folder or similar. (From what I have been reading online writing a file like this doesn't require any Android permissions? Is that correct?)

I haven't found the right info online that will help me achieve this. Below is my sample code and this works using the `user_data_dir` attribute from `App()` but the file is saved in a difficult location. Is there a way to modify the code so the file is saved in the Documents folder? I found this https://karobben.github.io/2021/03/12/Python/kivy-write2android/ and from what I could see "The absolute path of Download directory is: `/storage/emulate/0/Download`". So I tried this, Error! I also tried "`/Internal stoarge/Documents`, also **Error** `(no such file in both Errors)`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from os.path import join, dirname
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Main(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    path = StringProperty("Path")

    ToPrint = ["Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "A", "Kivy", "App"]


    def Export(self):
        self.path = join(dirname(self.user_data_dir), "Sentence.txt")

        doc = open(self.path, 'w')

        for word in self.ToPrint:
            doc.write(f"{word}\n")            
        doc.close()
    
    def build(self):      
        return Main()
    
TestApp().run()
```

And the KV file:

```
<Main>:
    padding: "20px"
    spacing: "20px"
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: app.path
    
    Button:
        text: "Click here to save the file"
        on_press: app.Export()
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [storage-path](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html) documentation on python-for-android and was able to save a test file in the Documents folder on Android.

First of all we have to request permissions for writing/reading on external storage as:

```
from kivy import platform
if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

Second we can look at what is the primary storage location as:

```
path = primary_external_storage_path()
print(path)
```

Once you know the path you could construct the Documents path relative to that.  I used `adb shell ls path` to surf through the directories.  I constructed the path as `os.path.join(path,'../../sdcard0/Documents/myfile2.txt'` and wrote some string int the file for testing.

Now we can pull the file from android using adb as `adb pull storage/sdcard0/Documents/myfile2.txt out/put/path/on/local/machine`.  That's it.  Here is a working piece of code:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import os
from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path

# get write/read permission
from kivy import platform
if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

path = primary_external_storage_path()
print(path)

with open(os.path.join(path,'../../sdcard0/Documents/myfile2.txt'), 'w') as f:
    f.write('good luck Jithesh, you are doing great!')

box = BoxLayout()

runTouchApp()
```